# Ether in ropsten testnet using metamask

Tags: ether, metamask, faucets

I have setup the metamask plugin on my browser successfully. Now i need some test ethers to test the things. I tried to get some from here : `http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/`  and `https://faucet.metamask.io/`
But i am not getting ethers in my account. Can somebody help me out? Thanks in advance

Comment: faucet.metamask.io works fine for me. It can take a few minutes to reflect some times. Can you post the transaction ID for the faucet request?

Comment: tx id : 0xa644c530c5f84e03b87649d29ee743fb8bc27b3414615354898d523f7282df4d

Comment: Looks like the transactions wasn't submitted to the chain. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xa644c530c5f84e03b87649d29ee743fb8bc27b3414615354898d523f7282df4d. For some reason the hash you provided has a ZWSP character before the last '8'.

Comment: I'm seeing that my test transactions also show similar behavior on the faucet. It could be the web app as ropsten health looks a-okay. http://status.infura.io/2252199

Comment: can you send me some please on ropsten :) 0xd74Ac5C91eeb934AA900e866c147FB6D0f00C113

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meanwhile the search for right faucet is on, you can always start mining on the testnet. I received around 15 test-Eths in about 8 hours - was enough to get started.

- In your Ethereum wallet, ensure you are on testnet (Develop -> Network should be testnet) Start mining by Develop -> Network -> Start mining.
- In console, geth --testnet --mine is the way to do

Comment: My address : 0x7F75E578b4c55a9f5c01eb7380149Ed5e33987C8

Comment: Please let me know when you transfer the test ethers @Manganese

Comment: Done, I am not sure community here will appreciate test-ETH transaction msgs here. Hence, editing that option out. Confirm when you got it. Tx

Answer (score 5):

Ropsten (and the faucet) has been having issues on and off recently. https://twitter.com/search?q=ropsten%20faucet. You can give Rinkeby a try. https://www.rinkeby.io/

Metamask supports rinkeby out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 4):

use https://faucet.metamask.io/ it is the better.
Note: when you ask ethers from the faucet wait a few minutes.
i was sent few ethers to the address in this post

Comment: I am waiting since last 7 days. @TahaBA Do you mean that you have sent any test ethers on Nicolas account?

Comment: Can you send some me too? My address : 0x7F75E578b4c55a9f5c01eb7380149Ed5e33987C8

Comment: you did have 12 ethers
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x7f75e578b4c55a9f5c01eb7380149ed5e33987c8

Comment: Yeah, sent by Manganese. Thanks for your words. One of my friend have also started working on ethereum, he also needs some test ether. If you can then the address is 0x7824A9aed0AB8844AE85Fc10a457ee768F2c4061

Comment: Done for your friend

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the official `Ethereum Wallet` I have faced similar issue with zero ether in wallet. I did following things

1. Switch to RopSten Test Network.
2. Once you switch you will see more option in `Develop` menu. This option would be of `Start Mining`. Select it.
3. Within few minutes you will see the ethers in your account.

I found this way much faster than any of the faucets. Some faucets required me to share data on Facebook/Twitter/Google+ etc.

I have earned 375 ether which mining which I can use for learning/deploying new contracts.